# Always show row with missings count in table1 package even if the number of missings is 0

Tags: r

Consider the code below:

```
library(table1)

test <- data.frame(
  cat1=c("a","b","b"), 
  cat2=c("a","b",NA),
  con1=c(1,2,3),
  con2=c(1,2,NA))

table1(~ cat1 + cat2 + con1 + con2, data = test)
```

[image]

The number of missings is displayed for both categorical and continuous variables iff there are missings in the first place. If the number of missings is zero, there is no row saying "Missings   0 (0%)". This is precisely what I want.

I can achieve this for continuous variables using `render.continuous` and specifying keywords described in `?stats.default()`, but the same thing does not seem to work for categorical variables. Furthermore, the "Missing" column ends up being doubled:

```
table1(~ cat1 + cat2 + con1 + con2, data = test,
       render.continuous=c(.="Mean (SD)",
                           .="Median [Min, Max]",
                           "Missing"="NMISS"),
       render.categorical=c(.="FREQ (PCT%)",
                            "Missing"="NMISS"))
```

[image]

How can I get one row PER VARIABLE indicating the number of missings (when the number of missings is zero) for categorical variables?

Comment: one option could be not using this package, and using gt or something similar instead....

Answer (score 2):

One option might be to pass the data frame to `gt_summary::tbl_summary()` where you specify `missing = "always"`.

```r
library(gtsummary)

test <- data.frame(
  cat1=c("a", "b", "b"), 
  cat2=c("a", "b", NA),
  con1=c(1, 2, 3),
  con2=c(1, 2, NA))

  test |> tbl_summary(missing = "always",
                      type = list(con1 ~ "continuous2", con2 ~ "continuous2"),
                      statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ 
                                         c("{mean} ({sd})", 
                                           "{median} ({min}), ({max})")))
```

[image]

Some work to customize is needed.